# Is it possible to make an oscilloscope that can integrate with music? "lissajous music"

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, animation-nodes, audio, curve-modifier

I want to make a Lissajous music using frequency value images of music or sounds in Blender. Like Spirograph Sound Visualizer... like oscilloscope music. sample : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqSvkNjWnnQ

Comment: and you did try what...!?

Comment: this isn't possible with geometry nodes right now...but if you search for animation nodes and music generated you will find good tutorials for that topic

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-4PFcTjPh4 I saw a video like this but I have no idea how to connect audio...

Comment: this is animation nodes, not geometry nodes. Search on google for "blender music visualizer animation nodes" and will find tons of tutorials for that.

Comment: thanks i will look. If I can't find it, can I ask you for help again?

Comment: I don't want to make a music visualizer. Here's what I want to do: watch from 4:16 seconds of this video I want to do this in blender it's an Oscilloscope. But I really want it to reflect sound frequencies with correct visuals, not random. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5efHsHqf18&t=190s

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.  The longer answer follows:

You can do this in Blender but it consists of two separate things, one is relatively easy, the other relatively hard.

If you want this to work in real time, that is, as the music is playing, you need to be able to read and process the music data in real time.  One way to do this is with a *socket server* in Blender that listens on a network connection for the music data to come from another source.  Another way is to use a playback library to read music data from a file and process it in real time.  A third would be to use serial input rather than a socket.

You can search on StackExchage for questions on all of these approaches.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831429/blender-api-bpy-and-socket-server) is about the socket approach, for example.

Next you have to write code to process the data into a format that can be displayed visually.  I know you don't like the phrase "music visualizer" but that's the search term you would use.  If you want simple amplitude display like a 'scope in its basic configuration, then you simply need to use a ring buffer to store data and write code to manipulate the coordinates of a curve to match the content of the ring buffer, ie, representing amplitude as the Z coordinate and time as the X.

For [Lissajous Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) visualization you would need code to calculate the curve from the current ring buffer. You would probably not want to do this directly in Python and you might not be able to do it fast enough even if you use the numpy library.